# How to get thread id from gmail for a certain email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail-api

I want to find the thread id for a certain email which I have sent from gmail. I went through the Gmail apis, in which there are methods to get the list of threads as well as a method which gives you all the messages related to that thread after you send the user id i.e email and thread id. I can use the list method to get thread id but is there any alternate way to get the thread id?

Comment: Have you sent the mail with the Gmail API, or do you want to find the mail with a given `Subject`, or something along those lines?

Comment: I have sent mail, now I want to fetch the replies on that email,I have the message Id ,But I want the thread id as the api suggest to get the conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just have the `messageId`, you could [get the message](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get), specifically asking just for the `threadId` of that message:

**Request**

```
usedId = me
id = 1514453c0800d5fa
fields = threadId

GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/1514453c0800d5fa?fields=threadId&access_token={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "threadId": "1514453c0800d5fa"
}
```

Then, just use this to  [get the thread](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/get):

**Request**

```
userId = me
id = 1514453c0800d5fa

GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/threads/1514453c0800d5fa?access_token={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Also, if you know the message is the first message in the thread, the `threadId` will be the same as the `messageId`, as in the example above.

If you don't have Google's own `messageId` but the [Message-ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-ID), you have to [list the message](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) as you said:

**Request**

```
userId = me
q = rfc822msgid:<Message-ID>

GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=rfc822msgid%3A%3C0000015148b39f7a-64856e69-3b6e-4e37-bff0-db4e26aae420-000000%40eu-west-1.amazonses.com%3E&access_token={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "15148b3a2f9a26a0",
   "threadId": "15148b3a2f9a26a0"
  }
 ],
 "resultSizeEstimate": 1
}
```

Comment: I tried,but I am getting response as "Login Required",when I am passing the authentication token also,I am not getting?

Comment: That should work. Could you show the code you are using?

Comment: I am trying with rest client, and  I am passing the user_id as my email address the message id and  the access token

Comment: @AjinkyaKathe I see. Paste the code in you question :) What you are saying should work, but there might be some small issue still!

Comment: Hey @Tholle I have the message id = <565838e9346b4_2deda8f9945741d@uelogi-H81H3-M4.mail> do you know how to convert it

Comment: @AjinkyaKathe Great! :) Updated the answer.